# How do you create a custom exception that handles user input taking range of values in account, in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm learning Python and I came across the following exercise:

> Create your own custom exception that will handle user input that is
>   NOT in the appropriate range of values you want them to enter (such as
>   a percentage mark must be 0 and 100) HINT: You will need a
>   definition!

The wording confused me, but from what I understand, I have to create a program that takes in a value that must be between 0 and 100 and has to incorporate an exception and a definition(?)

Here is what I have tried:

```
mark = 0

class Illegal(Exception):
    pass

while True:
    try:
        uMark = int(input("Enter a mark out of 100 to see if its valid or not: "))
        if 100 < uMark < 0:
            raise Illegal
        break
    except Illegal:
        print("Invalid mark")

print("Valid mark")
```

This, however, doesn't seem to be working because when I input, say, 200, as it returns `Valid mark`.

Comment: What value of `uMark` can both be larger than 100 and smaller than 0?

Comment: I think he wants to check if it is outside of the range 0-100. So more like `uMark < 0 or uMark > 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test can never be true:

```
if 100 < uMark < 0:
```

Chained comparisons use *and* to test all comparisons, as if you wrote:

```
if 100 < uMark and uMark < 0:
```

Integer values can't both be greater than 100 and at the same time be smaller than 0.

You need to use `or` instead, explicitly:

```
if 100 < uMark or uMark < 0:
```

Now this test is going to be true when `uMark` is either too small (below 0) or too large (over 100).

I'd re-arrange that test to be a little clearer to the human reader that `uMark` is outside the range:

```
if uMark < 0 or 100 < uMark:
```